# Create multiple columns based on values in single column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in dataframe(df['Values') with 1000 rows with repetitive codes A30, A31, A32, A33, A34. I want to create five separate columns with headings colA30, colA31, colA32, colA33, colA34 in the same dataframe(df) with values 0 or 1 in the new five columns created based on if the row is anyone of codes in df['Values'].

for Ex: df

```
Values  colA30 colA31 colA32 colA33 colA34
 A32       0     0      1      0      0
 A30       1     0      0      0      0
 A31       0     1      0      0      0
 A34       0     0      0      0      1
 A33       0     0      0      1      0
```

So if a row in df['Values'] is A32 then colA32 should be 1 and all other columns should be 0's and so on for rest of columns in df['Values'].

I did in the following way. But, is there anyway to do it in one shot as i have multiple columns with several codes for which multiple columns are to be created.

```
df['A30']=df['Values'].map(lambda x : 1 if x=='A30' else 0)

df['A31']=df['Values'].map(lambda x : 1 if x=='A31' else 0)

df['A32']=df['Values'].map(lambda x : 1 if x=='A32' else 0)

df['A33']=df['Values'].map(lambda x : 1 if x=='A33' else 0)

df['A34']=df['Values'].map(lambda x : 1 if x=='A34' else 0)
```

Comment: Looking for `pd.get_dummies(df.Values)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in many ways :

In `pandas` there is a function called `pd.get_dummies()` that allows you to convert each categorical data to a binary data. Apply it to your categorical column and then concatenate the dataframe obtained with the original one.
[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) is the link to the documentation.

Another way would be to use the library `sklearn` and its `OneHotEncoder`. It does exactly the same as above but the objects is not the same. You should use the instance of your `OneHotEncoder` class to fit it to your categorical data.

For your case I'd use `pd.get_dummies()`, it's simpler to use.